# Decomposing a loop in OpenMP

Tags: loops, fortran, openmp, fortran90, gfortran

I have several loops which follow this pattern:

```
do j = ms,mst    
   ic    = ic + 1                                                                                                                        
   df    = mm(j)*data(ic)
   dff(1:3)= vec(1:3)*df*qm
end do
```

As you can see, the variable `ic` is updated at every cycle of
`j` and the result of `ic` is used by the variable `df`. If I use 
atomic operation of OpenMP I could reduce the performance of OpenMP.
Do you know an efficient way to deal with these kind of loops in 
OpenMP?

Answer (score 3):

If `ic` is not changed apart from the increment (i.e. `data` is an array or a function w/o side-effects), there is a fixed relation between `j` and `ic`:

```
icStart = ic
delta   = icStart - ms + 1

do j = ms,mst    
   ic    = delta + j                                         
   df    = mm(j)*data(ic)
   dff(1:3)= vec(1:3)*df*qm
end do
```

This can easily be parallelized with `ic` and `df` being thread-private. You still need to take care about `dff`, as you will get a race condition as it is now...

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment! inside the same do loop I have an array qm_xyz%dat(ic) = df. Is it possible to declare such an array as private? I tried but the gnu compiler complains about the % symbol.

Comment: Why would you want to declare `qm_xyz` private? If two processes cannot have the same `ic`, there will be no problem in having it shared... Private arrays need to exist for every thread, so you would require n times as much memory (for n threads)!

Comment: thanks again really, dff shows a race condition because, lets say threads doing iterations j and j+m could write on the dff simultaneously? I still don't grasp the concept of race condition.

Comment: *All* threads will write to `dff` simultaneously! Therefore, it is not defined, which value will be present at any time.

Answer (score 2):

As you've written your code the value of `ic` is increased by `1` at each iteration, just as the value of `ms` is.  A straightforward parallelisation of the loop, something like

```
  !$OMP PARALLEL DO
  do j = ms,mst 
  ...
```

will distribute the work across threads giving each of them a discrete set of the values that `j` takes.  Simple static scheduling of a 64-trip loop (with `ms==1` and `mst==64`) across 4 threads will mean that thread 0 gets `j = 1..16`, thread 1 gets `j = 17..32` and so on.

However, without care on your part the values of `ic` won't get neatly split across threads in this way.  It looks to me, from the sample you've provided, as if the behaviour you want is for blocks of values of `ic` to accompany corresponding blocks of values of `j` -- they both increase by `1` at each trip round the loop.

Perhaps in the part of the code you haven't shown us `ic` is set to `ms+k` where `k` is some integer.  In that case you could simply drop `ic` from inside the loop and write

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO
do j = ms,mst    
   df    = mm(j)*data(j+k)
   dff(1:3)= vec(1:3)*df*qm
end do
```

Without knowing more about the relationship between `j` and `ic` it's difficult to offer more pertinent advice than this.  But the principle remains, rewrite `ic` as a function of `j` if you can and avoid difficulties inside the parallelised loop.